# Resizing UIView in runtime

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIView that's centered vertically and horizontally in my storyboard and has a fixed **height (100)** and **width (300)**. Now I want that uiview to be **resized (100, 100)** during runtime.

I have tried this so far but nothing worked.

```
let cgRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)

sampleView.draw(cgRect)
```

and

```
sampleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
```

and

```
sampleView.frame.size.height = 100
sampleView.frame.size.width = 100
```

Comment: check if you are using autolayouts, that can be the issue

Comment: did you set layoutconstraints in storyboard? if so, you have to set the constraints...

Comment: only center vertically and horizontally and a fixed width and height, nothing else

Comment: remove any constraints, or add your constraints as outlet and modify their constants

Comment: As @ReinierMelian mentioned, are you using constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hook the width and height constraints as IBOutlet and in

```
@IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    self.widthCon.constant = 100

    self.heightCon.constant = 100

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: what if the resizing will only happen if I pressed a button?

Answer (score 0):

To change the constraints during **runtime** via a button press you need to add it in an `IBAction`. In order to **animate** the change rather than it just jump, put the code in the `UIView` **animation** method:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed() {

    self.widthCon.constant = 100

    self.heightCon.constant = 100

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    // set hight and width by constraints.
}
```

or:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    // set hight and width by constraints.
}
```